# Translate Text in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento , I have a French store, In my checkout page , I have some text , How I translate into French , as of now it was displayed in English and I am using magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

you can use Inline  magento translate tool :
https://www.joomlart.com/tutorials/magento-tutorials/magento-tutorial-how-to-enable-inline-translation
Refer the above link

Answer (score 0):

in `app/locale/fr_FR` you have to create `Mage_Checkout.csv` and put your translations in this file. Example:

```
"Cancel Coupon","Annuler le coupon"    
"Address","Adresse"
```

After changes in this file, please flush magento cache.

Comment: for me , the text was wrapped into li tag like this <li>Online account with full order&nbsp;history</li> , how I convert this

Comment: In which file do you have this ```<li>``` element ?  You should replace content of this ```<li>``` with ```<?php echo $this->__('Online account with full order history'); ?>```. ```echo $this->__('Content to translate); ``` Is the way you sholud display text which you want to translate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will check and update you.

Comment: As per you said , I have created the file and its working fine , except this text Street Address 2, for that how i translate.

Comment: Street address 2 is rendered something like this: ```<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>``` you have variable pass to the string. so in your csv file you need to put:   
   
"Street Address %s","Adresse de rue %s"

Comment: Thanks its working fine.

Comment: Good, you're welcome. You can mark my answers as correct, for others.

Comment: Hi Sebastian T , the same logic is not applicable for payment method name why.

Comment: You need to search template  in which this string is rendered, and then translate it. Name of payment method is set in admin panel, so there you have to change store view and type french name

Comment: I searched it already , but the name came from xml file.

Comment: so in admin panel you have to change it.

Comment: you have default store view , change it to french and put your text there

Comment: can you please bit explain , where I have to search and put text

Comment: admin panel -> system -> configuration. on the left payment method. and there you have on the left top corner something like this : https://pagayo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/8464728baa55660b0dd4578a70e094a5.png Current configuration scope. change it to french and change payment method title

Comment: I already change to french as per you said , now my question is, where I find payment method title in admin panel.

Comment: as i said. admin panel ->system ->configuration. on the left sales->payment or something like this. there you have all payment methods

Comment: Thanks for the reply , now its working fine.